# Integrability of quantum spin models

Tags: quantum-spin, spin-models, integrable-systems

Based on this wiki page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenberg_model_(quantum)
The XXZ model is exactly Bethe ansatz solvable, but based on this paper (pape 5): https://arxiv.org/abs/1011.0380, the XZ model is non-integrable. The only difference between the two models is that the XZ model does not contain the $\sum \sigma^y_i\sigma^y_{i+1}$ term. This is very much confusing to me, because intuitively the XZ model should be much simpler, even though I understand that simplicity does not necessarily mean solvability or integrability. So given that I currently have no background knowledge of Bethe ansatz solvability, is there any intuitive way to see the non-integrability of the XZ model?

Answer (score 1):

At a quick glance it seems that at the value $g=1$ of the "non-integrability parameter", this XZ spin chain *is* quantum integrable [**edit**: only in absence of a transverse field, $h=0$! as commented by Ruben Verresen; see below]. Indeed, then <strike>(and only then)</strike> it's just the special case $\Delta=0$, known as the free-fermion point, of the XXZ spin chain <strike>-- with external magnetic field, but that is compatible with the integrability</strike>. [**Edit**: More generally, for $g\neq1$ (and still $h=0$) it is the point $\Delta=0$ of the Heisenberg XYZ chain, which is also a free-fermion model, and again integrable.]

(In case you'd like to know a bit more about the quantum integrability of the XXZ spin chain you could take a look at [my notes on arXiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/1501.06805) or the references therein.)

---

**Edit.** Just to wrap up this discussion let me add a little more. Integrable models are very special, and are rare. Typically, a modification will break its integrability. Having fewer terms might make the hamiltonian look simpler, but it will typically break integrability. (You could also drop, say, the interaction term between two given sites $i,i+1$ while keeping everything else the same. Although this breaks translation symmetry, one could say that some sense the resulting hamiltonian is 'simpler'. It is certainly not integrable.)

Importantly, as stressed by Ruben Verresen in a comment below, the model in eq (12) of the OP's reference contains a *transverse* magnetic field for $h\neq 0$. Unlike a longitudinal field, this breaks integrability. For instance, it breaks the $U(1)$ symmetry of the spin in any single direction, so the quasiparticles (magnons: spin excitations) are not conserved, which makes it impossible to use the Bethe ansatz.

Comment: but the $\Delta=0$ case of the XXZ model is in fact the XY model, which is very different from the XZ model. Indeed the XY model is exactly solvable, but the XZ model seems not.

Comment: Exactly, XY = "XX0", XZ = "XY0".

Comment: Write the XXZ Hamiltonian via spin ladder operators $S^\pm = S^x \pm i S^y$ to see that the XY model describes the hopping of spin-z excitations (kinetic term), while the $\Delta$-dependent part of the XXZ chain is a sort of potential term. The XZ model seems to have a strange kinetic term, so from that point of view it's perhaps not too surprising that the inclusion of $g$ destroys the integrability.

Comment: what do you mean by XZ=XY0?

Comment: I'm used to the notation "XYZ" for a spin chain with different parameters in front of the x-, y- and z-parts of the spin interactions. Then "XXZ" means that the parameter in the y-direction is equal to that for the x-direction (as would "YYZ", though that is never used), and for "XXX" all the parameters are equal. "XY0" then has vanishing third parameter, and different parameters in the other two directions. (To me the notation "XY" and "XZ" is a bit ambiguous: you have to learn what is what.)

Comment: sorry that I should have made it clear that I was talking about the models with non-zero magnetic field in the $z$ direction. In this case XZ is not the same with XY0

Comment: Just to resolve the above issue: indeed, the model in equation (12) is non-integrable even for $g=1$ (if $h\neq 0$; of course if $h=0$ then the model can be mapped to free fermions for any value of $g$). Note that this is not a special case of the integrable XXZ chain, cause the latter requires the $U(1)$ symmetry around the $z$-axis (or more generally, whatever direction the eternal field is pointing in), which is absent in equation (12). BTW, @JulesLamers, those are some beautiful notes, thanks!

Comment: @RubenVerresen: Could you please detail what you mean by that mapping between the XY and XZ models? Is there a good reference you could point to? Cheers